# Prove $\lim_{h \to 0} \frac{\varepsilon_1 (h_1) h_1 - \varepsilon_2 (h_2) h_2 }{h_1 - h_2} = 0$

Tags: complex-analysis, limits

This limit came up while doing an exercise in complex analysis, and I am not too sure how to evaluate it, or if it is even true for that matter!

Formally let $\varepsilon_1 , \varepsilon_2 : \mathbb{C} \to \mathbb{C}$ be functions such that $\varepsilon_1(h_1), \varepsilon_2(h_2) \to 0, \ h = (h_1,h_2) \to 0$. Prove
$$ \lim_{h \to 0} \frac{\varepsilon_1 (h_1) h_1 - \varepsilon_2 (h_2) h_2}{h_1 - h_2} = 0 $$
For instance by adding and subtracting cross terms we get 
$$ \frac{\varepsilon_1 (h_1) h_1 - \varepsilon_2 (h_2) h_2}{h_1 - h_2} = \frac{\varepsilon_1 (h_1) (h_1 - h_2) - h_2(\varepsilon_2 (h_2) - \varepsilon_1 (h_1))}{h_1 - h_2}$$
But now I am left with
$$ \frac{\varepsilon_1 (h_1) - \varepsilon_2 (h_2)}{\frac{h_1}{h_2} - 1}$$
Which doesn't really seem to help me. Any ideas?

Comment: It's false: Consider$ (x^2-2y^2)/(x-y)$

Comment: Thank you for the answer, I'll try something else then!